# Android openCV camera not working correctly

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to get into openCV for android. So I started to look on tutorials and finally got openCV working on my android app.

So the probelm in the camera preview looks like this:

The only things I found in the logcat are these:

```
2019-09-29 00:56:36.458 28721-28721/de.corestudio.opencvtest E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV

2019-09-29 00:56:41.244 28721-28742/de.corestudio.opencvtest E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

2019-09-29 00:56:36.546 28721-28721/de.corestudio.opencvtest E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
```

So I tried to fix them but nothing I found fixed them.

[image]

[image]

My main_activity.xml looks like this:

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCamera2View
        android:id="@+id/myCameraView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:show_fps="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And my MainActivity.java

```js
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

    CameraBridgeViewBase cameraBridgeViewBase;
    Mat mat1, mat2, mat3;
    BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(permission()){
            cameraBridgeViewBase = findViewById(R.id.myCameraView);
            cameraBridgeViewBase.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
            cameraBridgeViewBase.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

            baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
                @Override
                public void onManagerConnected(int status) {

                    switch (status){
                        case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:
                            cameraBridgeViewBase.enableView();
                            Toast.makeText(mAppContext, "Success", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            super.onManagerConnected(status);
                            Toast.makeText(mAppContext, "Failure", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mat1 = new Mat(width,height, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mat2 = new Mat(width,height,CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mat3 = new Mat(width,height,CvType.CV_8UC4);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mat1.release();
        mat2.release();
        mat3.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
    {

        mat1 = inputFrame.rgba();

        return mat1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(cameraBridgeViewBase!= null){
            cameraBridgeViewBase.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        super.onPause();
        if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are problems due OpenCV", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(cameraBridgeViewBase!= null){
            cameraBridgeViewBase.disableView();
        }
    }

    private boolean permission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
    {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
        50);
        }else{
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know about the rest of your code, but opencv's java camera on android ONLY works in landscape mode. The diagonal lines are a clue that this may be your problem, as it is what you see when yo try to render something to the screen that doesn't match the width of it. Now if putting it in landscape fixes it, you can always fake being in portrait mode with your icon placement etc.

I've used it but it may be easier for you to take a standard android camera feed and place that into a mat to mess with.

Comment: @JohnLord but when I use the front camera it works. Is it maybe my back has two cameras?

Comment: unlikely.  It could be an issue with the max resolution though.  I originally tried someone else's sample code when i implemented it into a document detection app that makes pdfs from the camera.  That code broke at high resolution when trying to draw on the screen.  If you are doing detection or something like that you wouldn't want full resolution anyway as the program will simply downscale it to something like 320x200, and that processing has huge overhead.  This assumes you made sure you chose different ids for each camera and aren't reading from a non-existent 2nd front camera.

Answer (score 1):

Just Change `JavaCamera2View` to `JavaCameraView`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in android 10. After a lot of trial and errors, I found that the following method must be implemented in the main activity:

```
@Override
protected List<? extends CameraBridgeViewBase> getCameraViewList() {
        return Collections.singletonList(mOpenCvCameraView);
    }
```